# Hyper-V machine stuck in starting

Tags: hyper-v

I have some issues with starting my virtual machines in Hyper-V. 

My setup:

- Hyper-V version 10.0.14393.0
- My host: Win 10 with the latest updates.
- Virtual machines: win 10, win 8.1, win 7 x86

The problem is that *sometimes* the machine get stuck in "starting..." state. 
I can solve the problem by killing the vmcompute.exe but then the machine might run into problem shutting down. (I have made a script for that if anyone is interested). 
Same issue but no permanent solution: https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/configmgr/2008/12/20/virtual-machines-found-stuck-with-status-starting-in-hyper-v-workaround/

The problem is that it is happening quite often and not only for me. I have several friends with the same problem and I can't find any solution to the problem. 
Otherwise, the virtual machines works perfectly when they have started.

 
Thanks.

 
**Solution found**
The problem was that after anniversary update for Windows 10 our anti-virus program F-secure and Hyper-V were having problems with each other. 
The problem was solved by adding wmwp.exe in F-secures excluding list.